# How do I mock a function called inside the function that I am testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, mocking, pytest

My file structure is like this:

```
pytests/
├── moduleA/
│   ├── functions/
│   │   └── process_moduleA.py
│   └── test_process_moduleA.py
└── utils/
    └── archive.py
```

in process_moduleA, I have the function I am testing:

```
from pytests.utils.archive import archive_process
def arch():
    archive_process(
            param1, param2
        )
```

and my test function is like this:

```
from pytests.utils.archive import archive_process

@patch('pytests.utils.archive.archive_process')
def test_arch(mock_archive_proc):

    arch()
    mock_archive_proc.assert_called_once()
```

I am just trying the most basic example of creating a mock of a function and checking if the function has been called once. However, the function never gets mocked and it runs the actual function. The mock is hence never called.

I have tried using:

`mock_archive=mocker.patch.object(pytests.utils.archive, 'archive_process', return_value=mock_archive_response)`

and then checking if mock_archive was asserted, but it does not work either. I have also tried using patch decorator but I get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by changing the object I was patching.

```
@patch('pytests.moduleA.functions.process_moduleA.archive_process')
def test_arch(mock_archive_proc):

    arch()
    mock_archive_proc.assert_called_once()
```

Here, I changed the path of the object to be patched from the path of the original function to the path of the function object being called inside my main file which has the function I am testing.

Comment: please accept your answer if it solves the problem you have raised by your question. On my opinion yours is a good answer and you can accept it. In SO it is possible to accept its own answer.

Answer (score 0):

When the module loads, `arch` is defined ***before*** the patch ever occurs.
In this situation, I would recommend using dependency injection over mocking.

However, to successfully mock you could try reloading the module after the patch occurs.

```
import importlib
from pytests.utils.archive import archive_process

def test_arch(mock_archive_proc):
    with patch('pytests.utils.archive.archive_process') as mock_process:
        importlib.reload(process_moduleA)
        arch()
        mock_archive_proc.assert_called_once()
```